# Pin block element to center of bottom of screen?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a block element centered horizontally, and at the bottom vertically. Here's what I'm trying:

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}
```

It's showing up on the bottom right, partially overflowing off the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: left and right cannot be applied at the same time...

Comment: Could you show your other code. Also, what exactly do you mean by "bottom". Do you mean the bottom of the entire website or the bottom of the physical browser view area?

Comment: You might want to try `margin: 0 auto;` instead of the left right thing...

Comment: @MikeG `margin: 0 auto` will not affect `fixed` position elements (nor `absolute`, for that matter).

Comment: @MikeG it's `fixed`, it's automatically the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a negative left margin equal to one half of the width of the element, such as:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -152px;
```

The `right: 50%` does nothing.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/VgPUZ/